# connected components labelling

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a task of using connected components labelling to group similar pixels and assign them a unique int label, and at the end derive the overall count of objects in the image.

This will be done after I convert a given image from a grey image to a binary image using an appropriate thresholding alogorithm and value. I have done this.

My question is in connected components labelling, can I use the already existing program which I have of converting a grey image to a binary one to count the objects? If yes, would I be labelling objects which are above the threshold value?

Comment: Could you clarify the question more? It isn't quite clear what you're asking.

Comment: i want to know how I can implement a connected components labelling to count the number of objects in my image. I've updated my question to make it more clear. I've threshold the image from greyscale to binary by making a copy of the pixels of imageOne and manipulating them, now using the pixels of imageOne(binary) I want to perform the connected components labelling...please help me, I don't know how to start, I know I gotta scan the the image left ot right and top to bottom each individual pixel at a time. but I don't know how to check the neighbours and how to label them. @RyanCarlson

Comment: my problem starts at PNGImage imageThree = new PNGImage(imageTwo.getWidth(), imageTwo.getHeight()); , after I copt the pixels from imageTwo I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, you should use the two-pass connected component labeling algorithm. Either with 4-connectivity or 8-connectivity. A simple and illustrative explanation of the algorithm can be found on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_labeling), complete with pseudocode and all which should be fairly straight forward to translate into Java.

You should start there and if you have any specific implementation question, such as "how do I check the neighboring pixel values?", you should post the question here on StackOverflow. Questions like "show the code for algorithm X" are a bit too general to be able to provide a concise answer. Even if I tried, the answer would never be as simple, illustrative, or explanatory as the Wikipedia entry.

I hope this helps, and please get back if you have questions about any implementation-specific details.

Comment: how do I know if the pixel is the foreground or background?...im trying the first pass atm...:)

Comment: also how do I assign a label?...if (imageTwo.getRed(x-1, y)==imageTwo.getRed(x, y)){ then how do I assign a label?

Comment: The thresholding in your code sets all values to 255 that are below the threshold. I assume then that dark pixels signify foreground in the original image?

Comment: I assume that `imageThree` is your label image. Then you simply set the current position in `imageThree` to the label value, e.g., `imageThree.setRGB(x, y, label, label, label)`. You also need to keep track of equal labels.

Comment: Note that in the condition checks on the Wikipedia page, the first and second condition check seem to be in the wrong order. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419066/java-image-connective-component/19971853#19971853) for more information.

Comment: I got PNGImage imageThree = new PNGImage(imageTwo.getWidth(), imageTwo.getHeight()); to copy the values from imageTwo(); how do I compare the the current pixel to the left one? this is what I got and it gives me errors, if (imageTwo.getRed(x-1, y+1) == imageTwo.getRed(x, y)==255){

Comment: sorry I just saw ur link to the other question...i'll study it and get back to ya

Comment: Since you have followed up on this answer I would appreciate it if you would mark it as accepted.

Comment: hey I got the first pass to work...it gave me about 184 objects, can you help me with the second pass?

Comment: I can help you. Post a new question to StackOverflow, "How do I merge the labels in connected component labeling", and let me know by commenting on this thread when the question is up. That way other users that might have an even better answer can help you as well.

Comment: hi mags I've posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065394/how-do-i-merge-the-labels-in-connected-component-labeling