# How do I merge the labels in connected component labeling

Tags: java, image-processing, computer-vision, labeling

Hi I have to find out how many objects I have in an image.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling
```

I need help with storing the equivalence between neighbours and also the second pass. This pass gives me 173 or so objects and is the first pass. I would like to store equivalences (when they occur) and then in the second pass to be able to just replace the corresponding equivalences with the lowest equivalent value.

Comment: You should not remove your code from the question. It will make answers referring to the code difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence table can be implemented using a `HashMap`. Each time you find a label that is equivalent to another label, just add that relation to the hash map.

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> equivalenceTable = new HashMap<>();
```

So whenever you find two labels that are equal, just put them in the equivalence table.

```
private void storeEquivalence(final Integer label0, final Integer label1, final Map<Integer, Integer> table) {
  if (table.keySet().contains(label0)) {
    table.put(label1, table.get(label0));
  }
  else if (table.keySet().contains(label1)) {
    table.put(label0, table.get(label1));
  }
  else {
    table.put(label0, label1);
  }
}
```

So when you identify that `region[x-1][y]` and `region[x][y-1]` are equal, you should check if the labels are different (they should be) and update the equivalence table if the are by calling

```
 storeEquivalence(region[x-1][y], region[x][y-1], equivalenceTable);
```

Then in the second pass you simply replace each label that has a value in the equivalence table.

```
for (int x = 1; x < imageTwo.getWidth(); x++) {
  for (int y =1; y < imageTwo.getHeight(); y++) {
    if (equivalenceTable.keySet().contains(region[x][y])) {
      region[x][y] = equivalenceTable.get(region[x][y]);
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot...so after region [x][y]= Math.min(region [x-1][y], region [x][y-1]); if there is an equivalence do i declare storeEquivalence (region [x-1][y], region [x][y-1],equivalenceTable);?

Comment: If both if statements `if (imageTwo.getRed(x-1, y) !=0)` and `if (imageTwo.getRed(x, y-1) !=0)` are true, then you should check if the labels are different and store them in the equivalence table if they are (if they are the same they obviously don't need to be stored in the table). I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: after my...region [x][y]= Math.min(region [x-1][y], region [x][y-1]);...if (region [x-1][y] != region [x][y-1]){
storeEquivalence (region [x-1][y], region [x][y-1],equivalenceTable);...netbeans is telling me i cannot reference a non static method from a static context...what should i do?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make `storeEquivalence` static (change the method signature to `private static void storeEquivalence(...)`).

Comment: ok i get it to work and it compiles...but how do i print how many objects i've got after the second pass? i've updated my code accordingly

Comment: it prints: "after the first pass, the algorithm counted: 173 objects" "after the second pass, the algorithm counted: {} objects"

Comment: ok now it prints the whole hash table...for example: {2=4,3=4...etc}....i want a final object count that eliminates the let's say 1=4 or 2=5...so everything that five is now 2...so the object count cuts down...do you know how i could achieve this?

Comment: If you have done the second pass as shown in the answer, the `region[][]` container will contain only the labels for the final objects. So for example, if your hash table is `{4=3,5=3,7=6}` then `region[][]` will only contain the labels `{1,2,3,6}` and all elements in `region[][]` with label 1 will be one connected component, all elements with label 2 will be one component, and so on... Just count the number of different labels in `region[][]` to get your object count.